# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net

I use VS2015 to write the following code in VB language, but there is some mistakes. I cannot find the mistake.

```
Private Sub BottonCreatePlaylist_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BottonCreatePlaylist.Click
    UserName = txtUserName.Text

    If UserName = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a user name!")
    Else
        Dim ExPlaylistDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim ExPlaylistService As New TempService.ServiceSoapClient
        ExPlaylistDoc.LoadXml(ExPlaylistService.getPlayLists())
        AllLists = ExPlaylistDoc.DocumentElement

        Dim playlists As Xml.XmlNodeList = AllLists.SelectNodes("PlayList")
        Dim playlist As Xml.XmlNode
        Dim n As Integer = 1

        For Each playlist In playlists
            If playlist.Attributes.Count > 0 Then

                Dim check As String = playlist.Attributes(0).Value

                If UserName = check Then
                    n = 0
                End If
            End If

        Next

        If n > 0 Then
            If ExPlaylistService.CreatePlaylist(UserName) Then
                MessageBox.Show("New User Created")
            End If
            getPlaylist()
            displayList()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("User has exsited!")
            txtUserName.Clear()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

It shows the mistake in "ExPlaylistDoc.LoadXml(ExPlaylistService.getPlayLists())". Service component worked perfectly. I added the service reference to client component. The client component did not work.The following is the output.

'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'H:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TemperatureClient\TemperatureClient\bin\Debug\TemperatureClient.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0xf10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1878 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1204 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'H:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TemperatureClient\TemperatureClient\bin\Debug\TemperatureClient.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\3.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: TemperatureClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in mscorlib.dll
The program '[5040] TemperatureClient.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like the settings for the web service are missing from the config file

Comment: Whatever is causing your program to exit, it is very unlikely to be that ConfigurationErrorsException.  The exit code says it isn't.  And has nothing to do with your code snippet.  Getting that exception isn't very unusual, tends to be caused by an old user.config file from a previous project with the same name.  Keep debugging to get closer, set a function breakpoint on System.Environment.Exit